# Upload an image using AJAX and plain old javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am learning AJAX techniques through David Flanagan's excellent book: JavaScript: The Definitive guide. There a section on file uploading
with an HTTP POST request. It says there, and I quote,  that "the XHR2 API, allows you to upload files by passing a File object to the send()
method".

I'll put David's example snippet here and then what I'm doing [which is almost the same thing:

```
// Find all <input type="file"> elements with a data-uploadto attribute
// and register an onchange handler so that any selected file is
// automatically POSTED to the specified "uploadto" URL. The server's
// response is ignored.

whenReady(function() {  // this function is defined elsewhere in the book. It serves the same purpose as jQuery(document).ready()
    var elts = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); // all input elements
    for(var i = 0; i < elts.length; i++){
        var input = elts[i];
        if(input.type !== "file") continue;     // skip all but file upload elts
        var url = input.getAttribute('data-uploadto');  // get upload url
        if (!url)   continue;

        input.addEventListener('change', function(){    // when user selects a file
            var file = this.files[0];       // assume a single file selection
            if(!file) return;               // If no file, do nothing
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create a new request
            xhr.open('POST', url);          // POST to the URL
            xhr.send(file);                 // Send the file as body
        }, false);
    }
});
```

I am trying to replicate the same idea with an `<input type="file">` element in my html. That's all I have, included the following JavaScript in the bottom of the html page:

```
<script>
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
input.addEventListener('change', function(){
var imageFile = input.files[0];
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) console.log('Image has been uploaded');
}
request.open('POST', /* I type here the url for the root directory of the site / html file I'm working with */);
request.send(imageFile);
}); 
</script>
```

Notes:

1. The type of file I'm trying to upload is an image.
2. I am working under the assumption that the image I'm trying to upload doesn't need some PHP script to do soemthing with it.
3. As you can see, I'm using plain old javscript,
4. I know it's know working because I am not seeing the image file I am supposed to have uploaded through the javscript snippet.

So my question here is: is there soemthing wrong with the javascript here (I don't see any console errors)? or,  Which other mechanism, using ajax would allow me to upload an image?

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: If you have no server side scripting, you could get something working with webdav and PUT statements I think, but without Server Side scripting I don't see how your post request could work

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste it (I'm not writing directly here). I just pasted it now.

Comment: you want server-side language to process the upload. client-side languages can be modified/manipulated so that would mean anyone could upload anything to your server/host. Example, evil person uploads a php file that will scan your host directory and remove all files? or do much worse things... I recommend you keep reading the book as it should explain the difference between server-side and client-side languages which normally cover any advantages/disadvantage

Comment: Ok. What type of functionality should the server-side script perform? I just want to upload the image, not proccess / edit it in some way. Again, I'm just replicating the technique from the book and the author doesn't seem to be using any server-side script.  NewToJS: The idea of uploading a malicious script to the server and executing it there crossed my mind, but in this case I just want to upload a picture. I know I'd have to do validation to ensure someone isn't uploading a script to the server. Here, I'm just interested in having the technique working.

Comment: Well validating it using javascript "client-side language" isn't going to be secure is it since the client can modify it hence the use of server-side scripts and by "process" I mean process the upload. Copy the script from the book word by word and see if the that every uploads the file because I think you will find it doesn't upload anything and won't without some form of server-side processing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using FormData to send the file up to the server.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", input.files[0]);
request.send(formData);
```

But you are going to need logic on the server to read the file and save it. Think about what happens if we could just randomly push any file to any server.

Comment: "But you are going to need logic on the server to read the file and save it. Think about what happens if we could just randomly push any file to any server."

This could be the answer to the question (perhaps I've asked the wrong question). I used a formData object as you suggested, and sent that object with the .send() method. When the request is done I get the message "Image has been uploaded" in the console (which I assume means the technique is working fine). So, would that mean that I need a server-side script to create the file I want to upload?

Comment: @Ariel you will see that message in the console because you have told it to log that message if the ajax post is a success by listening to the ajax request status. Hence `if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200)`

Comment: @epascarello That's the part I may not be understanding (I don't know much about server-side): I just want to upload an image ( I understand the security issues about allowing a user submit any type of file), but do I still need a server side script to perform some action on the image file?

Comment: @Ariel yes, how else will the server know the file is an image and safe to upload if you don't tell it what you want to allow/accept as a upload? Think of your application as a dummy, it knows nothing. You have to code it to know what it should and shouldn't accept. what you want and what you don't want clients to do... this is why it's called programming. client-side languages are run in the client browser, server-side languages are run on the host/server which cannot be changed/modified by the client.

Comment: @NewToJS correct. But wouldn't that mean that the upload was successful? That is, all the image per-se was POSTed to the server. I think I am asking a dumb question here. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: @NewToJS "yes, how else will the server know the file is an image and safe to upload if you don't tell it what you want to allow/accept as a upload? ...." . So, basically I have to have a server-side script to allow the image to be saved to the server? (That is, the server is rejecting -implicitly- the upload with the technique I'm using?).

Comment: @Ariel No, all that means is a successful call had taken place using ajax. Ajax can be used for passing data, not just uploading so ajax doesn't know anything about your image or the upload process, ajax is just passing the image to the page you request the post to via ajax but since you don't process the image/post it will do nothing but return a status of `200` which triggers your console log. I think you should do more research on ajax as you might be starting with something more complicated than you can handle.

Comment: @Ariel the server isn't rejecting the image, it just isn't doing anything with it because you haven't told it to do anything with it... you have no server-side code.

Comment: @NewToJS "... ajax is just passing the image to the page you request the post to via ajax but since you don't process the image/post it will do nothing but return a status of 200...". I think you've just explained the problem here. I though I was using ajax to upload the image and save it in the directory (because I'm specifying a directory as the URL for the request... and I assumed - mistakenly -  that would work, in some way, as it would happen if I copy and pasted a file on a directory in my computer). Thanks for the patience bro. I knew I was missing something obvious here.

Comment: @Ariel Well ajax doesn't work that way. Ajax works the same as a normal contact or media form, post/get via url but rather than pushing/sending the client with the data ajax will allow you to make that request in the background while keeping the client on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to use FileReader(), this code will produce base64 of image.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
    input.onchange = function(e) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
             console.log(this.result);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
```

```html
<input type="file"/>
```

Comment: But this isn't going to upload anything.... if anything this will display a preview of the upload but nothing will be saved to the server.